# pyspark DF.show() error after converting RDD to DF after zipWithIndex

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I seem to be following the documented ways of showing a DF converted from an RDD with a Schema. But clearly there is some minor but significant point I am missing. As follows then:

```
# Original schema + Index for zipWithIndex with variations on this
schema = StructType(result_df.schema.fields[:] + [StructField("index", LongType(), True)])
rdd = result_df.rdd.zipWithIndex()
df = spark.createDataFrame(rdd, schema)
#df.select("*").show()
print(schema)
```

The schema is shown as follows before Action executed:

```
df:pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame
  ARRAY_COLS:array
     element:string
  index:long
```

schema:

```
StructType
 (List(StructField
 (ARRAY_COLS,ArrayType(StringType,true),false),
  StructField(index,LongType,true)))
```

As soon as I perform the Action with the .show it blows up. In this case I have done things dynamically but not really necessary.

FULL listing

```
from functools import reduce
from pyspark.sql.functions import lower, col, lit, concat, split
from pyspark.sql.types import * 
from pyspark.sql import Row
from pyspark.sql import functions as f

source_df = spark.createDataFrame(
   [
      (1, 11, 111),
      (2, 22, 222)
   ],
   ["colA", "colB", "colC"]
                             )

intermediate_df = (reduce(
                lambda df, col_name: df.withColumn(col_name, concat(lit(col_name), lit("_"), col(col_name))),
                source_df.columns,
                source_df
         )     )
intermediate_df.show(truncate=False)

allCols = [x for x in intermediate_df.columns]
result_df = intermediate_df.select(f.concat_ws(',', *allCols).alias('CONCAT_COLS'))
result_df.show(truncate=False) 

result_df = result_df.select(split(col("CONCAT_COLS"), ",\s*").alias("ARRAY_COLS"))
result_df.show(truncate=False) 

#######

schema = StructType(result_df.schema.fields[:] + [StructField("index", LongType(), True)])

rdd = result_df.rdd.zipWithIndex()
df = spark.createDataFrame(rdd, schema)
df.select("*").show() 
print(schema)
```

Comment: There are many errors on pyspark answers in this regard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem becomes clearer if you look at `rdd`:

```
print(rdd.collect())
#[(Row(ARRAY_COLS=[u'colA_1', u'colB_11', u'colC_111']), 0),
# (Row(ARRAY_COLS=[u'colA_2', u'colB_22', u'colC_222']), 1)]
```

Notice that it's a tuple containing a `Row` object and the index.

I see two alternatives:

1) Extract the values from the `Row` and `map` the `rdd` to a tuple matching `schema` using a tuple comprehension:

```
rdd1 = rdd.map(
    lambda row: tuple(row[0].asDict()[c] for c in schema.fieldNames()[:-1]) + (row[1],)
)
df1 = spark.createDataFrame(rdd1, schema)
df1.show(truncate=False)
#+---------------------------+-----+
#|ARRAY_COLS                 |index|
#+---------------------------+-----+
#|[colA_1, colB_11, colC_111]|0    |
#|[colA_2, colB_22, colC_222]|1    |
#+---------------------------+-----+
```

This creates a new `tuple` with the contents of each record:

```
print(rdd1.collect())
#[([u'colA_1', u'colB_11', u'colC_111'], 0),
# ([u'colA_2', u'colB_22', u'colC_222'], 1)]
```

2) Build a new `Row` by adding an `index` and unpacking the existing `Row`:

```
rdd2 = rdd.map(lambda row: Row(index=0, **row[0].asDict()))
df2 = spark.createDataFrame(rdd2, schema)
df2.show(truncate=False)
#+---------------------------+-----+
#|ARRAY_COLS                 |index|
#+---------------------------+-----+
#|[colA_1, colB_11, colC_111]|0    |
#|[colA_2, colB_22, colC_222]|1    |
#+---------------------------+-----+
```

Now each record is a `Row` with an `index` added:

```
print(rdd2.collect())
#[Row(ARRAY_COLS=[u'colA_1', u'colB_11', u'colC_111'], index=0),
# Row(ARRAY_COLS=[u'colA_2', u'colB_22', u'colC_222'], index=0)]
```

But because of this, you don't need to use `schema` in the call to `createDataFrame`:

```
spark.createDataFrame(rdd2).show()
#+---------------------------+-----+
#|ARRAY_COLS                 |index|
#+---------------------------+-----+
#|[colA_1, colB_11, colC_111]|0    |
#|[colA_2, colB_22, colC_222]|1    |
#+---------------------------+-----+
```

Method 1 uses the existing `schema` you've defined while method 2 may be a little more compact, code wise (but requires hard coded `index=`).

Comment: There seem to be a lot of examples out there that are not clear in pyspark, would you not agree? In Scala seems to be easier... Cheers